# GitLab folder doesn't upload

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I have a repository, some of the files there are Git LFS files. I have a server, an .ipynb and an Android app. The folder with the Android app won't upload at all. It would show an icon like [image: this] (the upper one, LymeDetectorDesign), it would reload the repository root on click, and if I Git clone this repository, the LymeDetectorDesign folder remains empty. I tried doing Git lfs push, tried to commit again, but it says everything is up to date, though I clearly have lots of files if the Android app folder.

Comment: LymeDetectorDesign looks like a git submodule, not a LFS reference. You have to git clone with --recurse-submodules in order to pull the files for the submodule.

Comment: @KingChungHuang but what if I want to see the files in that folder in the browser? How can I do that?